# EFCore Migrations; what is the role of HasData( ... ) in the ContextModelSnapshot?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.2

I had in mind that when a migration is run, the database data is updated, a snapshot is taken and we thus end up with a synced system:

- database data looks like X
- ContextModelSnapshot looks like X

Later I can either update the data in the database, or I can update the data in the snapshot and then, depending on what I did, I can tell EFCore migrator to either:

- update the database (if i edited the snapshot) and generate a sql/fluent style update of the database DB so that the db will be back in sync with the snapshot => using the db table as "what was" and the snapshot as "what shall be"
- update the snapshot (if I updated the db) and again generate some sql/fluent style updates to sync the two, but this time using the snapshot as the reference of "what was" and the db as reference of "what shall be

In either case a migration can be created, and I'm just telling EF which is the authority on what the data should be

Fast forward to creating my migration; I'd actually advanced one db relative to another db, and the snapshot wasn't synced with either thanks to another migration that had been applied elsewhere but I wasn't privy to. So I instead wrote an SQL that would generate snapshotty looking code (concat strings together to create c# code) from the "what was" db, and dropped my manually created code into the snapshot, then asked EF to migrate (with the "what shall be" DB configured in the app settings)

It generated some of what I expected; some update queries.. But mostly it generated inserts for data that already existed so now I get PK violations. I thus guess I'm completely wrong about how the migrator works internally. If I was in a situation where the only frames of reference for how I wanted my DB migration to go, were two DBs (one production, one my dev) how would I go about creating a migration if ef core was out of sync with both?

Comment: See [Model seed data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#model-seed-data) documentation topic.

Comment: @IvanStoev I read that, but I didn't quite get the answer i'm looking for. HasData() is present in my model blahblahdbcontext.cs, my contextsnapshot.cs and my migration.designer.cs, and my data is changed in the db that the web.config is pointing to - so when EFcore is doing a migration with add-migration, which data set is it treating as the current("what was"), and which is it treating as the future ("what shall be")?

Comment: Every migration cs file has associated designer.cs file. The model in designer.cs is "what shall be". And the "what was"  is taken from the previous migration (if any) "what shall be". I'm not sure what the common ModelSnapsot.cs is - most likely the copy of the "last applied" or something like that.

Comment: But the designer file doesnt exist until after the migration is added, so where does the migrator get its info of what to put in the designer file?

Comment: From the current (at the time Add-Migration command is invoked) code model. It's a full model snapshot, not just the difference.

Comment: So the hasdata in my context file (it also has mappings etc), versus the previous designer.cs file. Does it mean that contextsnapshot doesn't really have any purpose ?